# Springboot - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, javabeans

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object
for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

When I try to call this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/invite", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showInvitePage(ModelAndView modelAndView,@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    return modelAndView;
}
```

this is the thymeleaf page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-activate" th:action="@{/invite}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
        <h2 class="form-activate-heading">Nodig een student uit</h2>
        <p>Vul hier het e-mailadres in van de student die je wil uitnodigen:</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control input-lg"
                   placeholder="Username" tabindex="1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control input-lg"
                   placeholder="Username" tabindex="2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Invite"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

It's odd because I have another method which is almost a copy of this one and it works perfectly fine here:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showRegistrationPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user){
    return modelAndView;
}
```

and the thymeleaf page:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Registratie</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control input-lg"
               placeholder="Username" tabindex="1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control input-lg"
               placeholder="Email" tabindex="2"/>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" th:field="*{encryptedPassword}" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"
               placeholder="Password" tabindex="3"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation"
               class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="4"/>
    </div>
```

The only thing I might think of is that when you call the invite method, a user is already logged in and is doing the actual inviting. When registering, no user is logged in yet.

EDIT:

I removed the thymeleaf th:field from the input fields and used the classic way and it works fine now.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg"
                   placeholder="Username" tabindex="2"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg"
                   placeholder="Email" tabindex="2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this exception because there is no `user` object to which Spring can bind.  So add one to the model in your GET method:

```
@GetMapping("/invite") //use shorthand
public String showInvitePage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User()); //or however you are creating them 
    return "theFormNameWithoutTheExtension";
}
```

Then your POST would have the processing:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String showRegistrationPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    //do your processing
    return "someConfirmationPage";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how come it works in the register method without adding the object to the get methode and it didn't for the invite get method?

Comment: `showInvitePage` is (eventually) called when the URL is requested.  You are calling `showRegistrationPage` when the button is submit button clicked.  So you're essentially providing Spring a bean to "store" data.